# Create List View Quick Action that calls a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-button, quickaction, lightning-quickaction, lightninglistview

I want to add a quick action button into a record ListView which calls a flow.

When I open the list view options, I can not see the quick actions that I created. It says "New Quick Action" but it never populates the actions.

[image: List is empty]

Anyone figured it out before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [appears](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mass_quick_actions_create.htm&type=5) that only Create a Record or Update a Record action types are available for list view actions.

> IMPORTANT You can perform a mass quick action on only the following
> quick action types:  **Create a Record  Update a Record**

There is an [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZOFQA4) for this on trailblazer community.

Apparently there was a [workaround](https://www.xbaf.com/flow-list-buttons) before however latest comments indicates it is not working anymore.

Comment: As a solution I created a list button with URL type and as a path I entered the flow and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a visualforce controller to pass the list of records into the flow. Vibhor Goel has the best writeup I've seen:

https://www.accidentalcodersf.com/2020/07/use-flows-from-list-views-salesforce.html